# Can CListCtrl display dynamic width images

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

CListCtrl can show image with image list like following code.

```
m_imList.Create(64,64,ILC_COLOR24,10,20);
CBitmap * pBmp = NULL;
pBmp = new CBitmap(); 
pBmp->LoadBitmapW(IDB_BITMAP1);
m_imList.Add(pBmp,RGB(0,0,0));  
delete pBmp; 
m_list.SetImageList(&m_imList,LVSIL_SMALL);
```

But can i show variable width size image?

Comment: I think you are looking for custom draw `CListCtrl`, where you manually draw each image, for example to preview an image directory.

Comment: You don't give much information about your use case. A sketch of what you want the result to look like, could be helpful. I'm assuming you want to show thumbnails of a set of images. Create the image list with the maximum size of the thumbnails. Before adding each image to the image list, scale it proportionally so that it "fills" the dimensions of the thumbnail image in the best possible way without clipping. Fill the remaining space with a background color or set the alpha value to zero to make it "transparent".

Comment: Say original image size = 1024 x 768, max. thumbnail size = 50 x 50. Scaled image width = 50, scaled image height = 50 * 768 / 1024 = 37. `BitBlt()` scaled image of 50 x 37 to temporary image of 50 x 50, centering it. Fill border on top and bottom with background color or set alpha value to zero. Add temporary image to image list.